# Explanation of "int factorial = 1" in this for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have this code which intends to explain how "for loops" work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Input a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        factorial *= i;
    cout << "factorial(" << n << ") is << factorial << "\n ";
    return (0);
}
```

What does the line `int factorial =1` do? Why is it needed?

Comment: Formatting your code helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int factorial = 1;
```

defines a variable with the identifier `factorial` and the type `int`. It is intended to hold the temporary results of the factorial calculation throughout all iterations of the `for`-loop and to hold the final result.

It is explicitly initialized with `1` because

1. It has to be initialized *somehow*; otherwise, undefined behavior will be the result as an uninitialized memory location will be accessed.
2. `0` would be bad because `0 * x = 0` for all real numbers while `1 * x = x` for all real numbers.

Comment: Why do we have to initialize their? is it not being initialized in the next line where int=1?

Comment: @Aljabra No, only `i` is initialized. `factorial *= i;` is equivalent to `factorial = factorial * i;`. As you see, `factorial` is used to determine the result, so it **has** to be initialized.

Comment: So basically everything in the statement in a for loop needs to be initialised seperately?

Comment: @Aljabra I don't really understand. Initializing `i` won't initialize `factorial` and `factorial` has to be initialized explicitly, so yeah, in a way "everything needs to be initialised seperately."